# Uploading Media to LinkedIn with LinkedIn API using a public S3 media URL

Tags: linkedin-api

I am trying to upload a video/image to LinkedIn using the LinkedIn API. The documentation provides an example for uploading from a local file, which looks like this:

```
curl -v \
 -H "Content-Type:application/octet-stream" \
 --upload-file ~/Downloads/sample.mp4 \
"https://www.linkedin.com/dms-uploads/C5505AQH-oV1qvnFtKA/uploadedVideo?sau=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cubGlua2VkaW4tZWkuY29tL2FtYnJ5L2FtYnJ5LXZpZGVvZWkvP3gtbGktYW1icnktZXA9QVFHVkdRS0FtS05oM2dBQUFYd19ObG1uZzVYcllXajEzZjIybXh4LW55SGVBclVKcE8y"
```

However, I would like to upload the media directly using a public S3 media URL. When I upload the media using this approach, the upload completes successfully. However, when I retrieve the media status from LinkedIn, I receive a response indicating that the media is corrupt. The S3 media URL is publicly accessible.

I have tried to upload the media to LinkedIn using the following code snippet:

```
const uploadResponse = await axios.put(
    uploadUrl,
    S3MediaUrl,
    {
        headers: {
            "X-Restli-Protocol-Version": "2.0.0",
            "LinkedIn-Version": 202305,
            "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
            Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken,
        },
    }
);
```

after trying to retreive the media using the Get request that is the answer that I get:

```
{
    "owner": "urn:li:person:******",
    "processingFailureReason": "CORRUPTED_ENTITY",
    "id": "urn:li:video:********",
    "status": "PROCESSING_FAILED"
}
```

I expected the media to be successfully uploaded and for the media status retrieved from LinkedIn to indicate that the upload was successful. However, I encountered the issue of the media being reported as corrupt, after what looked like a successful upload
.

[LinkedIn documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/videos-api?view=li-lms-2023-05&tabs=http#how-to-upload-videos)

Comment: did you get this resolved? I have the same issue. Would like to know the any findings if you have